Help with indexing smart contract events
Was having a hard time with subxt and indexing smart contract events hence asking for help
I want to look for an event on a specific smart contract i deployed
can someone help provide some existing examples. Thanks
I have the current approach
#[subxt::subxt(runtime_metadata_path = "metadata.scale")]
pub mod node_runtime {}

pub async fn listening_for_events() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync + 'static>> {
    println!("Listening for events...");


    let client = OnlineClient::<PolkadotConfig>::from_url("wss://rpc2.paseo.popnetwork.xyz").await?;

    // Define your contract address
    let my_contract_address = "x";
    let contract_account_id = subxt::config::polkadot::AccountId32::from_str(my_contract_address).unwrap();

    // Subscribe to finalized blocks
    let mut blocks_sub = client.blocks().subscribe_finalized().await?;

    while let Some(block) = blocks_sub.next().await {
        let new_block = block?;
        let block_number = new_block.header().number;
        println!("New block #{block_number} created!");

        // Get events for this block
        let events = new_block.events().await?;


        println!("Events: {:?}", events);
// WHEN RAN THIS WAS THE PRINT STATEMENT WHICH RAN GIVING 2 EVENTS PER BLOCK AND THE LOOP WASNT ENTERED

        // Filter for ContractEmitted events from your specific contract
        for event in events.find::<node_runtime::contracts::events::ContractEmitted>() {
            println!("Contract event1: {:?}", event);
            match event {
                Ok(contract_event) => {
                    println!("Contract event2: {:?}", contract_event);
                    if contract_event.contract == contract_account_id {
                        println!("Contract event received from our contract: {:?}", contract_event);
                        // Decode and process the event data
                        match decode_event_created_event(&contract_event.data) {
                            Ok(course_created) => {
                                println!("X event: {:?}", course_created);
                                
                            },
                            Err(e) => println!("Error decoding  event: {:?}", e),
                        }
                    }
                },
                Err(e) => println!("Error processing ContractEmitted event: {:?}", e),
            }
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
#[derive(Decode,Debug)]
struct X {
    X: u32,
    X: String,
    X: String,
}

fn decode_event_created_event(data: &[u8]) -> Result<x, Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync + 'static>> {
    x::decode(&mut &data[..]).map_err(|e| e.into())
}


Is that when pointing to a dev node or a live one? A dev node will tend to have ~two events for an empty block. I would also print the extrinsics via something like: new_block.extrinsics().await?.iter().for_each(|e| print!("{:?} {:?}", e.pallet_name(), e.variant_name())) to see if the blocks you're seeing actually contain any contract related extrinsics.
